# Unexecuted PHP code in ob_get_contents

Tags: php, output-buffering

I'm trying to capture the output of my controller class (yii framework) the following way:

```
ob_start();
$controller->actionView(4);
ob_end_flush();
assertContains('needlestack', ob_get_contents());
ob_clean();
```

edit:

Seems it has to do with the use of

To my surprise, the output contains unexecuted PHP code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="description" content="<?=Yii::app()->params['description']?>" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= bu('/images/favicon.png') ?>" />

    <?= $this->renderPartial('//site/_header_js'); ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/usr/bin/assets/905db112/detailview/styles.css" />
<title><?= CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= bu('css/style.css')?> "/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= bu('css/form.css')?> "/>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?= bu('js/commonjs.js') ?>"></script>


</head>

<body class="<?= $this->bodyClass ?>">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Header -->
        <?= $this->renderPartial('//site/_body_header'); ?>

        <?= $content; ?>    
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <?= $this->renderPartial('//site/_body_footer'); ?>
    <?= $this->renderPartial('//site/_footer_js'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

How could PHP echo unexecuted PHP code? How can I get the resulting HTML?

Comment: I bet the use of `ob_get_contents()` is a total red herring. Did you try the same thing without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<?=` syntax is [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), and it looks like they're disabled in your php install. You should set `short_open_tag` to `1` in the `php.ini` file, or you can use `ini_set( "short_open_tag", 1 );` at the top of your script.

Comment: The short tags work on Apache, just not when I try to capture them using ob_get_contents(). I tried to init_set them to 1 in the unit test file I'm in, but that didn't help :-(

Comment: Ah, sry. Apache in XAMPP and phpunit use two different php.inis. It works now :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Are [short open tags](http://php.net/short_open_tag) enabled? If they aren't, syntaxes like `<? ... ?>` and `<?= ... ?>` won't be parsed.